# Iterate over map for assignment avoiding nested loop in Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I want iterate over map in such a way that it can assign a accuserlookup__c field from account to it's relevant contact conUserlookup__c field without nested for loop and update contact in the end.

Bellow code is how I am getting data in map inside my after trigger helper.

```
map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsWithAccount = new map<id,List<Contact>>();
            List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, name, accuserlookup__c , (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : setAccountIds];
                for(Account acc : accounts){
                    contactsWithAccount.put(acc.id, acc.Contacts);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to start from the contact object:

```
Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Account.accuserlookup__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :setAccountIds];
Contact[] updatedContacts = new Contact[0];
for(Contact contactRecord: contacts) {
  if(contactRecord.conUserlookup__c != contactRecord.Account.accuserlookup__c) {
    contactRecord.conUserlookup__c = contactRecord.Account.accuserlookup__c;
    updatedContacts.add(contactRecord);
  }
}
update updatedContacts;
```

No map is necessary here.